# Looping through array of arrays using ngFor in angular 7

Tags: angular

I need to display a list on my angular 7 UI. The list is categorized by Product Type as seen in the screenshot. There should also be a space after each product type

[image]

I have tried something but that doesnt display like in the screenshot. Could somebody tell me where am i going wrong

UI

```
<div *ngIf="AllocationDetails && AllocationDetails.MissingProducts">


                      <table *ngFor="let key of AllocationDetails.MissingProducts; let i = index">
                        <tr>
                          <th>{{key[i].ProductType}}</th>

                        </tr>
                        <tr *ngFor="let key of AllocationDetails.MissingProducts; let j = index">
                          <td>{{key[j].ProductName}}</td>

                        </tr>
                      </table>


    </div>
```

This is how the array looks like

[image]

JSON format

```
[[{"ProductId":2844,"ProductName":"*DO NOT USE* City Plan LLC","ProductType":"Strategic Partnerships"},{"ProductId":2840,"ProductName":"*DO NOT USE* Baha'i Separate Managed Account","ProductType":"Strategic Partnerships"},{"ProductId":2851,"ProductName":"Test Special Opportunities Evergreen Fund Ltd.","ProductType":"Strategic Partnerships"},{"ProductId":2852,"ProductName":"Test Spafid Multi-Strategy Fund","ProductType":"Strategic Partnerships"}],[{"ProductId":2745,"ProductName":"Test Special Opportunities Fund III Master LP","ProductType":"Commingled Fund"},{"ProductId":2854,"ProductName":"Test Select Opportunities II Ltd.","ProductType":"Commingled Fund"},{"ProductId":2746,"ProductName":"Test Structured Income Fund I Ltd.","ProductType":"Commingled Fund"},{"ProductId":2749,"ProductName":"Test Structured Income Fund II Ltd.","ProductType":"Commingled Fund"},{"ProductId":2778,"ProductName":"Test Structured Income Fund II-A Ltd.","ProductType":"Commingled Fund"},{"ProductId":2794,"ProductName":"Test Hedge Fund Opportunities II Ltd. Continuing","ProductType":"Commingled Fund"}],[{"ProductId":2828,"ProductName":"ICBC Quantitative HengSheng Choice Pooled Fund.","ProductType":"Sub-Advisory "},{"ProductId":2853,"ProductName":"HEC SPV II Cayman LP","ProductType":"Sub-Advisory "},{"ProductId":2800,"ProductName":"TP ETP Offshore LP","ProductType":"Sub-Advisory "},{"ProductId":2829,"ProductName":"ICBC Quantitative Xincheng Choice Pooled Fund Trust.","ProductType":"Sub-Advisory "},{"ProductId":1841,"ProductName":"Brightgate Absolute Return FIL","ProductType":"Sub-Advisory "}],[{"ProductId":2827,"ProductName":"Test Alternative Income Strategy.","ProductType":"Liquid Alternatives"},{"ProductId":1603,"ProductName":"Test Alternative Core Fund","ProductType":"Liquid Alternatives"}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looping through a nested array, and you only access to `key[x]`. What you want is `key[i][j]`

This line is wrong:

```
 <td>{{key[j].ProductName}}</td>
```

Replace it with this:

```
 <td>{{key[i][j].ProductName}}</td>
```

Comment: What about ProductType. My output has to bee like the screenshot in the post. ProductType followed by productNames

Comment: As seen in the screenshot Strategic Partnerships , Commingled Fund ,Sub-Advisory and Liquid Alternatives are Product Types. The ones below them are product Names. If you see my first array . It has three elements with product type that is Strategic Partnerships and product names would be different

Comment: I get error Cannot read property 'ProductName' of undefined using what you  suggested. I have updated the post with json if that helps

Comment: He doesn't need to re-declare key neither

Comment: I tried this but it displays on productnames . I need to display the product types as well as seen in the screenshot .Here is what i tried  <ng-container *ngFor="let group of AllocationDetails.MissingProducts">
                
                
                   <tr *ngFor="let post of group">
                        <td>{{post.ProductName}}</td>
                        
                    </tr>
            </ng-container>